# Laravel Creating Service provider argument 1 must implement service provider

Tags: laravel, caching, service, laravel-4, ioc-container

Hi I am creating a custom cache service class which will abstract the caching layer out of my repository. However I am running into some trouble as I'm getting this error:

`Argument 1 passed to Task::__construct() must implement interface MyApp\Cache\CacheInterface, none given, called in /var/www/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 792 and defined`

My class is as so follows:

```
<?php namespace MyApp\Cache;

use Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager;

class CacheService {

 /**
  * @var Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager
  */
  protected $cache;

  /**
   * @var integer
   */
  protected $minutes;

  /**
   * Construct
   *
   * @param Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager $cache
   * @param string $tag
   * @param integer $minutes
   */
  public function __construct(CacheManager $cache, $minutes = 60)
  {
    $this->cache = $cache;
    $this->tag = $tag;
    $this->minutes = $minutes;
  }

  /**
   * Get
   *
   * @param string $key
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function get($key)
  {
    return $this->cache->tags($this->tag)->get($key);
  }

  /**
   * Put
   *
   * @param string $key
   * @param mixed $value
   * @param integer $minutes
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function put($key, $value, $minutes = null)
  {
    if( is_null($minutes) )
    {
      $minutes = $this->minutes;
    }

    return $this->cache->tags($this->tag)->put($key, $value, $minutes);
  }

  /**
   * Has
   *
   * @param string $key
   * @return bool
   */
  public function has($key)
  {
    return $this->cache->tags($this->tag)->has($key);
  }

}
```

And in my model I have the following;

```
<?php
use Abstracts\Model as AbstractModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use CMS\APIv2\Objects\Entity;
use MyApp/Cache\CacheInterface;

class SprintTask extends AbstractModel
{


    /**
     * @var CacheInterface
     */
    protected $cache;

    public function __construct(CacheInterface $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }


public static function scopegetAssignedSprint($id) {
    $key = md5('id.'.$id.get_class());

    if($this->cache->has($key))
    {
        return $this->cache->get($key);
    }

    $user = static::where('uid', $id)->lists('sprint_id');

    $this->cache->put($key, $user);

    return $user;
}
```

And I have a cache service provider which is as follows;

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\Cache;

use MyApp\Cache\CacheInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CacheServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = false;

    /**
     * Register
     */
    public function register()
    {

        $this->app->bind
        ('MyApp\Cache\CacheInterface',
            'MyApp\Cache\CacheService');

    }


}
```

Any ideas how I can setup this service provider correctly to be used in any mode/controller/repo etc??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to do it like this :

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\Cache;

use MyApp\Cache\CacheInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager;

class CacheServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = false;

    /**
     * Register
     */
    public function register()
    {

        $this->app->bind('MyApp\Cache\CacheInterface',function(){
            return new CacheService(CacheManager $cache);
        });

    }
}
```

**I just updated it bases on Trip comment**

Comment: I get this error still `Class 'MyApp\Cache\MyApp\Services\Cache\CacheService'` not found and had to add a comma between CacheManager and $cache. any ideas whats going wrong? I am using this code now; `$this->app->bind('MyApp\Cache\CacheInterface',function(){
            return new MyApp\Cache\CacheService(CacheManager, $cache);
        });`

Comment: have you dumped your data `composer dump` so that they regenerate the loader again ? and another thing you should not add a comma between `CacheManage` and `$cache` , last thing you should check your code you have an issue for missing `$tag` parameter in `CacheService` constructor

Comment: This might have worked if you had your leading backslash on the return statement class reference: "return new \MyApp\Cache\CacheService(CacheManager $cache);" or simply "return new CacheService(CacheManager $cache);" since you're already in the \MyApp\Cache namespace.

The lack of a leading backslash caused PHP to look for your class in the wrong place ("MyApp\Cache\MyAppCache...').

Comment: thanks @Trip I just updated the code based on your note, and you are correct . thanks

Answer (score 1):

When service container tries to instantiate **TaskRepository**, it sees that one of its constructor arguments is an object of class **CacheService**. Therefore it first tries to instantiate this object so that it can be later passed to **TaskRepository** constructor.

Your **CacheService** defines two required arguments. When Container tries to instantiate **CacheService**, it needs to provide values for both attributes and pass them to the constructor. Service container normally uses the type hint of constructor arguments to identify what service should be injected. In your case you require **$tag** variable to be passed, but as it has no type hint in constructor signature, therefore service container has no idea what should be passed to the constructor.

That's why you're getting the error - it simply says that service container is not able to resolve one of required dependencies of **CacheService** class.

There are multiple solutions to that problem.

First of all, you'll need to add a type hint to **$tags** argument.

If $tags is an object of some class that service container is able to instantiate, add a type hint to CacheService constructor signature.

If instantiating **$tags** object is something that you want to handle yourself, create the object in one of your service providers and bind it using container's **bind()** method.

If **$tags** is soomething that cannot be managed and injected by the container, you'll need to instantiate CacheService yourself and bind it using **bind()**.

If **$tags** is something that cannot be managed by service container, e.g. array, you'll need to instantiate TaskRepository yourself, not via the service container.

You can read more about dependency injection in Laravel here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container

Comment: is there a laravel4 doc?

Answer (score 1):

The short version is that you can't use dependency injection on an Eloquent model. The IoC magic doesn't work on them, and since your AbstractModel extends the Eloquent Model class, the IoC magic doesn't work here. (Partial explanation by Taylor Otwell -- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3862#issuecomment-37364543)

There are a couple of ways to get this basic idea to work:

(1) Use a Repository for the Model and inject your CacheService there. Since Eloquent is a repository-like ORM, this can be confusing and tedious.

(2) Register your CacheService through a new Facade and use it like Laravel's built-in Cache facade, directly in your model without injection -- MyCache::has($key). It can be set up as a Singleton if you'll never need to connect to two different caches. (L4: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades, L5: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades)

(3) Use a combination of #1 and #2, as outlined here: http://dfg.gd/blog/decoupling-your-code-in-laravel-using-repositiories-and-services

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to inject an instance implementing `CacheInterface` into `SprintTask`, but in your service provider, you're providing an instance of `CacheService` which does not implement `CacheInterface`.

You need to implement that interface in `CashService` in order to be able to pass it to `SpringTask`:

```
class CacheService implements CacheInterface
```